# Swift iOS : UIPageController inside UINavigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building an app based on a `UINavigation` controller as the main entry.

I would like to add a mini tutorial with a `UIPageController` (dots) inside the nav, but all the documentation I can find shows how to use `UIPageController`s as a main entry to an app.

When I attempt to put the usual code onto a custom-classed ViewController page that is accessed from the UINavigation Controller, (instead of on the main ViewController) it does not work.

Looking for advice or hints on where to look for this kind of thing.

Currently using Xcode 7.0 with Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `UIPageViewController` will work within a `UINavigationController`, and setting the `UIPageViewController` to "Horizontal Scroll" in the Interface Builder console will allow it to act as a dotted-tutorial style page progression.

Answer (score 0):

The control you're referring to is a [`UIPageControl`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427161638/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPageControl.html),

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/Art/uipagecontrol_intro_2x.png))</sub>

not a [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller):

[image]

You can embed page controls in every custom view controller.

Comment: Glorfindel, thank you for the reply. 

All the online tutorials I have seen recommend using UIPageViewController with the setting of "horizontal scroll" instead of "page turn", which results in the "dots" navigation. 

I will investigate the use of UIPageControl instead and hopefully that will get me where I'm going. 

I'll report back. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Reporting back, I did try out the UIPageControl, and though it should serve as an indicator for my purpose, it would require me to reconstruct all the code needed to perform the exact same functionality of using the UIPageViewController with the "scroll" setting enabled (instead of the default page-turn).
 

Fortunately, the exploration into UIPageControl did help me with the foundation I needed for implementing the UIPageViewController deep within an app. 


It all worked out in the end. Thanks again for your help!